# can't convert empty cells to float from csv import

Tags: python

I'm importing test data and keep running into an issue 'ValueError: could not convert string to float:'
edit: the blank cells are always at the end of the list and all list aren't the same length.
I think the reason for this is that I have blank cells being imported in some of my lists. Can anyone help me to get rid of them or set them to zero?
I'm just trying to plot the data and I can't seem to solve this error.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
with open('TestFile.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    Cs = []
    Rs = []
    Qs = []
    for row in islice(readCSV,3,None):
        R = row[0]
        C = row[1]
        q = row[2]
        Qs.append(q)
        Cs.append(C)
        Rs.append(R)
plot(Qs)
```

and here's some sample data, saved as .csv:

```
Sample 1        Sample 2        Sample 3        Sample 4        Sample 5    
Load    Time    Load    Time    Load    Time    Load    Time    Load    Time
N   sec N   sec N   sec N   sec N   sec
0.007   2.3 0.524   2.3 0.344   2.3 0.914   2.3 1.086   2.3
0.052   2.32    0.577   2.32    0.397   2.32    0.973   2.32    1.161   2.32
0.112   2.34    0.637   2.34    0.457   2.34    1.041   2.34    1.235   2.34
0.172   2.36    0.689   2.36    0.517   2.36    1.101   2.36    1.31    2.36
0.232   2.38    0.749   2.38    0.577   2.38    1.168   2.38    1.385   2.38
0.292   2.4 0.816   2.4 0.637   2.4 1.235   2.4 1.46    2.4
0.352   2.42    0.884   2.42    0.704   2.42    1.303   2.42    1.535   2.42
2.44    0.959   2.44    0.779   2.44    1.37    2.44    1.61    2.44
2.46    1.033   2.46    0.854   2.46    1.445   2.46    1.685   2.46
2.48        2.48    0.929   2.48    1.52    2.48    1.752   2.48
        2.5 1.003   2.5 1.595   2.5 1.834   2.5
```

any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test for a value in the cell before assigning, and replacing it with zero if you need to:

```
R = row[0] if row[0] != '' else 0.0  # choose a test adapted to your values
C = row[1] if row[1] != '' else 0.0
q = row[2] if row[2] != '' else 0.0
```

The test you perform must be adapted to the type of values you encounter in your file.

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried adding the code you suggested and it worked perfectly first time. I'll accept the answer in 9 minutes (it won't let me do so earlier than that!) Thanks very much, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help, cheers. [there was a typo in the code I proposed; the indices used in the comparison were all zero - I fixed it now]